# Most efficient way to extract a cell value from a scraped table

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape exchange rates from xrates.com. I use this code to get the table with the rates.

```
Set Topic = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(1) _
                   .getElementsByTagName("TBODY")(0)
```

I don't want to hard-code row numbers because they might change. Therefore I prefer to use the currency names and I'm lookin for the most efficient way to do that.

1. Loop through all rows and check each one against the name I want. I want half a dozen out of 53 on the site. Therefore I would have to conduct 6 searches.
2. Search for the name I want and then parse the element where it was found.

Instinctively, I prefer the second but parsing will take a lot of code. What I really want is the row number (element number) where the name was found, something like `getElementByContent`, and then read the element's cells instead of the document's text. This is a very common requirement in my scraping efforts but since that idea doesn't appear to be supported I think I probably approach the problem in a wrong way.

Comment: You'll need to loop over the table rows - it's not a loot of code to do that.  You only need to loop the rows once - you can check for each currency as you go.  https://ncsullivanblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/16/scraping-html-table-with-vba/

Comment: `.querySelector("td.nc a[href='https://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=GBP&to=CAD'")` is an option (and substitute the GBP and CAD etc) but it doesn't play with `HTMLDocument` and you might only be able to use this by automating IE....

Comment: @Robin Makenzie Thank you for your suggestion. I did it with a loop. That way I didn't need to change the rest of my scraping macro.